# in java how can one check if there are spaces after a char

Tags: java, char

I am trying to see if there are spaces after a certain char, if there aren't I will count++ if there are then it won't, I have no idea how to do this! I am doing it in an if statement, and I know how to check for the letter but not if there are spaces afterwards. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work!

`if ((letter == '#')&&(letter+1!='\t')&&(letter+1 != ' '))`

Comment: Show us more code. If `letter` is a `char` you cannot get the next letter out of it.

Comment: Run this - `char c = '#'; System.out.println(c + 1); System.out.println((char)(c + 1));` You'll see both of the others will be true if the first one is - *always*.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the ultimate objective?

Comment: Regular expressions are great at things like this.  Without more context I can't really give you any specifics beyond an expression like `"#\\s+"`, but don't know what could actually come before the pound sign to make it more accurate..

Comment: my program can find the # but it is trying to find out if there are spaces afterwards, realizing that i cannot get the next letter out of the char what should i do Banthar?

Comment: in order to count the # there must not be spaces after it whether the space is a ' ' or '\t' but i do not know how to check for this...

Answer (score 1):

In Java your `letter` variable of type `char` is not a pointer like in C. So doing `letter+1` simply gives you the next letter (as in next in the character table, not your string) after `#`, which is `$`. So as a result your `$` will never be equal neither to `\t` nor to .

You may want to get the next character the same way you are getter the character into `letter` - as a separate variable, and check that against the tab and space. Like so:

```
int position = 0;
char letter = mystring.charAt(position);
char next = mystring.charAt(position+1);

if (letter == '#' && next != '\t' && next != ' ')
```

This is of course very crude and prone to errors, but I hope it explains your current issue.

There are better ways to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate your string and collect the character before the space...

```
public class CharCheck {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String string = "Check for spaces after a char";

        List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>( );

        for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

            if( string.charAt( i ) == (' ') ) {
                chars.add( string.charAt( i - 1 ) );
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Characters with spaces after them :");
        for(Character character : chars) {
            System.out.print(  character );
        }

    }
}
```

---

### RESULT

```
Characters with spaces after them :
krsra
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try java regular expression?

```
    String input = "# input for test";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("find");
    }
```